# How to check the number and IPs of kafka servers running in the cluster via kafka client?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-cluster

I have a requirement where we have to validate the health check of the system via one single rest point. The idea is to get the number of kafka nodes and their IP's in the cluster running actively via a kafka client.Does kafka provide any API in client to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, details about all the Kafka nodes in a cluster can be retrieve easily using the [`describeCluster()` method](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeCluster--) of the [AdminClient](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminapi).

For example:

```java
Properties adminProps = new Properties();
adminProps.load(new FileInputStream("admin.properties"));
AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(adminProps);

DescribeClusterResult describeClusterResult = adminClient.describeCluster();
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>(describeClusterResult.nodes().get());
for (Node node : nodes) {
    System.out.println("Node id=" + node.id() + " host=" + node.host() + " port=" + node.port());
}
```